# Creating Offline Test environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vmware-esxi, domain-controller, vmware-vsphere

So I'm trying to create a test environment that hosts a copy of one of the domain controllers in production and I was wondering if anyone has some insight on the best way to perform the "copying" of the domain controller. The production servers are running on Vmware vsphere 5.1 and the test environment will be on 5.1 as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a domain controller (or take a clone of one of the existing ones)
2. Move it to your test network, fire it up.
3. Seize all of the FSMO roles.
4. Use `ntdsutil` to clean up the old DCs that it can no longer contact.